# Markdown doesn't highlight the code

Tags: bug, markdown, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighter works strangely in the [current question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878920/convert-an-xml-node-to-string/).

[image]

The weird thing is that in other questions the highlighting works fine. Firstly, I supposed the system haven't detected the language, but copying snippets from other questions didn't enable it either.

What is the reason?

---

**UPDATE:** It looks like the system detected the language as XML, not JavaScript. Does it consider tags? If so, why it doesn't place [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag at the first place for detection?

Comment: It didn't detect the language *at all*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is tagged as XML and and JavaScript, at which point the highlighter cops out; it won't force a choice on you.

Add a language hint:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    ... js code block ...
```

to specify it manually.

From the [Formatting FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks):

> Prettify is used to add colour to the code, but only if the language can be **uniquely** determined given the tags of the question, or if manual hints have been provided

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Ah yeah. I have already added this assumption to the question. But why it does not consider JavaScript as a first tag then?

Comment: The JS tag might be more popular than XML when it comes to tagging, that does not mean that you can infer from that what code you posted. Because the language cannot be determined uniquely, it doesn't make a choice at all.

Comment: *In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess* -- Tim Peters, The Zen of Python.

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot!